# Why do I get an error saying split undefined?

Tags: javascript, split, discord

```
var anssep = answer.split(" ")
var answer = (" ")
if(anssep[0] == "send"){
  var toSend = answer.replace((anssep[0]+" "), "")
  bot.channels.cache.get("701888561640636510").send(toSend)
```

that is the code that should take what i type into console and print it on the discord server for this bot  but i get this error

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined

Comment: Answer is defined AFTER you try t split it. Hence the error

Comment: Also, I know it is not python but it be nice to have good indentation practice...

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to use `split` in a string called `answer` which has not been declared and defined yet. 
Swap lines 1 and 2 according to:

```
var answer = (" ")
var anssep = answer.split(" ")
```

Comment: That has worked to allow me to use the console again, but the console now isn't doing anything now.

Comment: I cannot understand what you mean. Can you update your question with the error?

Answer (score 1):

That error usually means you are trying to call a method of something undefined. In your case, it probably means the variable called answer is undefined but there's no way to be sure without knowing how that variable gets created.

Did you try debug the javascript source from a browser? You can stop in that point and see if your variable has a value or not.

Answer (score 0):

First establish that it is not undefined then ensure it is a string:

```
if(answer !== undefined){
  var anssep = answer.toString().split(" ")
} else {
 console.log('answer is undefined')
}
```